# Rewrite rule to use root files on a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to know how to use files located at a root level on a sub-domain.

I'm currently using sub-folders to manages languages on my website, with URLs like that:
http://www.example.com/es/page.html
(and I want to switch to http://es.example.com/page.html)

In my /.htaccess file, I have the following rule and it works like a charm:

```
RewriteRule ^(es|fr|de|br)/page\.html$ script.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

But how can I redirect to this /script.php?lang=es file (located at root) from a sub-domain located in a sub-folder (in "/es/" in this case) please?

Thank you

nb. Can I do this in /es/**.htaccess**? (easiest option would be to define *RewriteBase /* one level up in there, but I don't think it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es|fr|de|br)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ page.php?lang=%1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. `RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ another_name.php?lang=%1 [L]` should redirect to **another_name.php**, not page.php. It's like this rule simply converts xx.html into xx.php (and of course xx.php is not found).

Comment: Can't see any `another_name.php` in the question.

Comment: Based on your example, if I put `RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ script.php?lang=%1 [L]` it redirects to **page.php** instead of  script.php. I edited my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @sun where is subdmains root? htaccess can't rewrite any local path behind the document root of the current virtual host. In your case all (sub)domains must have one document root IMO.

Comment: I think it's because you put a `$` instead of a `%` before `{HTTP_HOST}`, now it works, thanks!